# The width of the inputs and the submit

Tags: html, forms, input, submit

I have a form and I want the submit to be the same width than the rest of the inputs. But the submit seems smaller. I simplified the case here. I use the Firebug or the Chrome inspector and it says that the inputs that are not submit have 4 pixels more. Can anyone explain why, where do that 4px come from?

I have the example simplified here to play: http://jsfiddle.net/Mq5bq/

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="admin_comprovar.php" method="post"><br />
  <input type="text" name="nom" value="name"/><br />
  <input type="text" name="mail" value="mail"/><br />    
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input { width:180px; padding: 0; }
input[type="submit"] { width:180px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to count borders and paddings *into* width/height:

```css
input {
    width:180px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mq5bq/3/)

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `<input type="text">` element has a border which adds to width.

But the submit button does not have the border. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mq5bq/2/) out.
The above example removes border.